# return variable within asynchron function in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, asynchronous, request

I've a little problem with nodeJS and their asynchron functions.
I need a function which does a GET request for getting some API data and then commits some data back into 2 variables to the function call for further use.
But the problem is, that I can't use the response data outside the asynchron request function to return some data.

Is there any possibility to realize that? If not how can I do something like that?

```
var geoData = function(address){
    // Google API Key
    apikey = 'XXX';
    // google API URL for geocoding
    var urlText = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='
                + encodeURIComponent(address)+'&key=' + apikey;
    request(urlText, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) 
        jsonGeo = JSON.parse(body);           
        console.log(jsonGeo.results[0].geometry.location);
    }
})
// Variable jsonGeo isn't declared here
latitude = jsonGeo.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
longitude = jsonGeo.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

return [latitude,longitude];    
};
```

Thanks so much and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Why don't you just add "latitude = jsonGeo.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
longitude = jsonGeo.results[0].geometry.location.lng;" into your request callback function ?

Comment: You cannot do that. Forget about `return` in continuation passing style; use a callback.

Comment: I've done this before, but it creates just undefined results at function call.

Comment: @elclanrs: Could you give me a little example for this way? Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend reading about async CPS to find out why what you are trying to do is not correct from a theory standpoint, of course you can do it, but it won't behave as you expect. Once you go async, there is no way back, you are trapped in async world.

Comment: What you try to do is contrary to the spirit of Node.js, but if you (for good or bad reasons) really want your function to return the results from your request, you must 1. before your request, define variables for your latitude and longitude, 2. in your call-back fill in those variable, 3. after your request code a loop polling if these values are already filled and if so, return them. If you understand me, try it out, post it as an answer and earn your *self-learner*badge. Else ask us to code it for you.

Comment: @km65 In any reason you can deasync you async function. For example,  use https://github.com/abbr/deasync

Comment: @km65 Or you can use Promise - https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of of returning something use a callback for geoData which will do the necessary task .

```
var geoData = function(address, callback){
    // Google API Key
    apikey = 'XXX';
    // google API URL for geocoding
    var urlText = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+encodeURIComponent(address)+'&key='+apikey;
    request(urlText, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            jsonGeo = JSON.parse(body);           
            console.log(jsonGeo.results[0].geometry.location);
            latitude = jsonGeo.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            longitude = jsonGeo.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
            callback([latitude,longitude]);
        }
    })    
};
```

use it like this

```
geoData('myaddress', function(arr){
    console.log(arr[0], arr[1]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast and helpful answer! That's the solution.

Comment: This async world is really a doom loop ;-) But this way it works! Thanks

Comment: Indeed, instead of fighting the async nature of node.js, adapt, adopt and enjoy it!

Comment: @Dirk: I'll try it ;-)